# Named parameters being passed as part of the url because of slashes

Tags: php, search, cakephp-1.3, slash

I am using `cakephp 1.3` and i want to search a record which contain / in string.
i have passed parameter as below.
Search params are as below.

```
Array
(
    [controller] => indents
    [action] => admin_index
    [named] => Array
        (
            [pr_no_data] => pr
        )

    [pass] => Array
        (
            [0] => no
            [1] => dip
            [2] => 002
        )

    [prefix] => admin
    [admin] => 1
    [plugin] => 
    [form] => Array
        (
        )

    [url] => Array
        (
            [url] => admin/indents/index/pr_no_data:pr/no/dip/002
        )

    [isAjax] => 
)
```

as you all can see my url params contain `admin/indents/index/pr_no_data:pr/no/dip/002` and now i want to search pr_no as defined in url.
How can i do this.? 
because search for / record passing values as passed parameter.
Please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your array, CakePHP sees part of the data as passed parameters. In the `pr_no_data` named variable, you see it references `pr` as it's value.

```
[named] => Array
   (
       [pr_no_data] => pr
   )
```

However, the remaining character string in the data is recognized as passed parameters because of the slashes. So it is reading them as part of the URL, not the `pr_no_data` variable.

```
 [pass] => Array
    (
        [0] => no
        [1] => dip
        [2] => 002
    )
```

What you need to look at is how you generate that variable before it is added to the URL. Perhaps you can change it to a pipe | separated list or a comma , separated list so it does not interfere with the URL and confuse cakephp.

```
pr|no|dip|002
pr,no,dip,002
```

Once cakephp receives the data, you can then convert them back to slashes if needed:

```
$passed = preg_replace('/,/', '/', $this->params['named']['pr_no_data']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the named parameter value using [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

The URL should be

```
admin/indents/index/pr_no_data:pr%2Fno%2Fdip%2F002
```

If you create the URL using the Html helper, then CakePHP should encode the value for you.

```
echo $this->Html->url(array(
    'prefix'=>'admin',
    'controller'=>'indents',
    'action'=>'index',
    'pr_no_data'=>'pr/no/dip/002'
));
```

Comment: i am searching record through form submit so its textbox value..so how can i do this...because i already tried urlencode its shown me 404

Comment: I assume this URL is the action for the form. How is that action attribute set?